# JavaScript - Enable submit button if function's value is true

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, submit

I would like to enable submit button only if the function func() returnes true, but i don't know how to get the value from the function  which is being called onblur event. I mustn't use anything but JavaScript. Can someone help?

Here is the code:

```
<script>

    function func(obj){
        if(obj.value.length > 4){
            alert("Longer than 4.");
            return false;
        } else if (obj.value.length < 2){
            alert("Shorter than 2.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

</script>

<form method="" action="">

        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onblur="func(this)"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
        function func(obj) {
            if (obj.value.length > 4) {
                alert("Longer than 4.");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                return false;
            } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
                alert("Shorter than 2.");
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This one did the job!  But as i said my primary concern had been how to get function's return value, because i will be having multiple functions, and only if those all are true submit should be made available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled) property of button element. Set it to false if condtion satisfy.

If `disabled` property value is true then button is disabled else enabled.

```js
function func(obj) {
  if (obj.value.length > 4) {
    alert("Longer than 4.");
  } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
    alert("Shorter than 2.");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("submitButton").disabled = false; // Set to false for enable button
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="" action="">

  <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onblur="func(this)">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" disabled>

</form>
```

Subnote:

`func` function actually not doing anything on return value that can be reduce.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function func(obj) {
        if (obj.value.length > 4) {
            alert("Longer than 4.");
            return false;
        } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
            alert("Shorter than 2.");
            return false;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("submitButton").removeAttribute("disabled");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers fellas!

Comment: Well, i guess it could be done this way, i tried it but it enabled submit even after one of the false ifs, maybe after some "tinkering". But my primary concern was how to get function's return value, because i will be having multiple functions, and only if those all are true submit should be made available.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable ("disabled" in the code below) depending on the criteria you gave and then the disabled state of your submit input (which I added an id to) is set to that variable.

```
<script>

    function func(obj) {
        var disabled = true;
        if(obj.value.length > 4) {
            alert("Longer than 4.");
        } else if (obj.value.length < 2) {
            alert("Shorter than 2.");
        } else {
            disabled = false;
        }
        document.getElementById("subInp").disabled = disabled;
        return disabled;
    }

</script>

<form method="" action="">

        <input type="text" name="text" id="text" onblur="func(this)"><br>
        <input id="subInp" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" disabled>

</form>
```